# jq produces `is not defined at <top-level>` error

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, jq

I'm seeing a `is not defined at <top-level>` when calling jq like so:

```
jq ".Changes[0].ResourceRecordSet.Name = word-is-here.domain.com" someFile.json
```

The error repeats for each word separated by a dash in the second side of the replacement. The full error is like

```
jq: error: word/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.Changes[0].ResourceRecordSet.Name = word-is-here.domain.com
```

I've tried escaping quotes in many different ways but that didn't help. (what I mean by this is doing "'"'" weird stuff, I'm still learning bash so I'm just trowing stuff at the wall until it sticks)

**EDIT:**
So I'm trying to run this in a bash script, and both side of the = signs are variables such as `jq --arg value "$value" --arg key "$key" '$key = $value' "$path"` (what I tried after a suggestion)

and got the error:
Invalid path expression with result ".Changes[0].ResourceRecor...

The json I'm using is as such:

```
{
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "do something",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "some name here to replace",
         ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a part of the json which allow us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: In future, please follow the [mcve] guidelines as closely as possible. Thanks.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca I've updated the question with a part of the json and elaborated on the other errors I got when I tried something different (i.e using args)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq '.Changes[0].ResourceRecordSet.Name = "word-is-here.domain.com"' file.json
```

Quote the string you are assigning. Or pass it to jq via an argument:

```
jq --arg foo 'words-here' '.Changes[0].ResourceRecordSet.Name = $foo' file.json
```

For passing the path to the key you want as an argument, a suggestion from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1493 might work:

```
jq --argjson path '["Changes",0,"ResourceRecordSet","Name"]' \
  --arg val 'word-is-here.domain.com' \
  'getpath($path) = $val' file.json
```

Comment: I just tried that and it worked via cmd line, but when I run it in a script like: `jq --arg value "$value" --arg key "$key" '$key = $value' "$path"`I get this error
"Invalid path expression with result ".Changes[0].ResourceRecor..."

Comment: amazing, so what worked specifically for me in the end was your last line there but no quotes around foo which I pass in as an arg. i.e jq --argjson path '["Changes",0,"ResourceRecordSet","Name"]' --arg foo "hello-world-blah" 'getpath($path) = foo' file.json

Comment: @capa_matrix - The problem in your first try (in the first comment) is that you used `--arg key` instead of `--argjson key`.  You want `key` to be understood as a JSON array, not a JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem (or at least the obvious problem) here is evidently the string: `word-is-here.domain.com`, since jq is interpreting the dash ("-") as an operation ("minus").

Unfortunately, since you haven't given us many clues, it's not completely clear what specifically needs to be changed, but a reasonable guess is that `word-is-here.domain.com` is intended as a fixed string.  If so, you would have to present it as a JSON string.  So in a bash or bash-like environment, you could write:

```
jq '.Changes[0].ResourceRecordSet.Name = "word-is-here.domain.com"' someFile.json
```

#### Specifying the LHS path via a shell variable

If the LHS path must be specified by a shell variable, it should if possible be passed in as a JSON array, e.g. using the `--argjson` command-line option; one can then use an expression of the form `setpath($path; $value)` to update the path.

If for some reason a solution allowing the LHS to be specified as a jq path is preferred, then shell string-interpolation could be used, though as with any such interpolation, this should be done with care.

Comment: unfortunately I'm using variables for both side of the equation, I've updated the question with those details and thanks for pointing that page out to me